# Universal image loader imageview doesn't update itself with spinner

Tags: java, android, xml, android-imageview, universal-image-loader

I'm using UIL to load thrumbs in a listview.

here is the imageview and the spinner in the **cell layout** :

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAlbum"
            android:layout_width="48dip"
            android:layout_height="48dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center|left"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/loading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

The list :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_restaurant"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I config the **loader** like that :

```
public void setImageLoader(ImageLoader imageLoader, Context context) {

        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
        ImageLoaderConfiguration _config;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
            _config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).memoryCacheExtraOptions(0, 0).discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75).taskExecutor(null)
                    .taskExecutorForCachedImages(null).threadPoolSize(3) // default
                    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
                    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
                    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024)) // default
                    .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024).discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
                    .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024).discCacheFileCount(100).discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
                    .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
                    .enableLogging().build();
        }
        else {
            _config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context).memoryCacheExtraOptions(0, 0)
                    // default/screendimensions
                    .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75).taskExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR).taskExecutorForCachedImages(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
                    .threadPoolSize(3) // default
                    .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
                    .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
                    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024)) // default
                    .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024).discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
                    .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024).discCacheFileCount(100).discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
                    .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
                    .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
                    .enableLogging().build();
        }
        if (!imageLoader.isInited()) {
            imageLoader.init(_config);
        }
    }
```

And in the **baseadapter** i use it like that :

```
private ImageLoader             _imageLoader;
private DisplayImageOptions     _options;
```

in the **constructor**

```
this._imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
this._options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.error).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .build();
Utils utils = new Utils();
utils.setImageLoader(_imageLoader, _activity);
```

In the **GetView()** :

```
    final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
                _imageLoader.displayImage(etablissement.getImgThumb(), cellHolder.imageIcon, _options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        spinner.invalidate();
                        view.invalidate();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                        String message = null;
                        switch (failReason.getType()) {
                            case IO_ERROR:
                                message = "Input/Output error";
                                break;
                            case DECODING_ERROR:
                                message = "Image can't be decoded";
                                break;
                            case NETWORK_DENIED:
                                message = "Downloads are denied";
                                break;
                            case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                                message = "Out Of Memory error";
                                break;
                            case UNKNOWN:
                                message = "Unknown error";
                                break;
                        }
                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);spinner.invalidate();
                        view.invalidate();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        spinner.invalidate();
                        view.invalidate();
                    }
                });
```

Everything works fine **BUT** the spinner stay instead of the imageview until you scroll the list the redraw the cells.. The imageview should refresh itself when the image is downloaded/got from cache or invalidate()

Here the list loading stay like that : http://imagik.fr/view-rl/45673

Here when i scroll down the imageview refresh : http://imagik.fr/view-rl/45674

Here when i re-scoll up the imageview refresh : http://imagik.fr/view-rl/45675

Any idea ??

EDIT:

The full adapter code (with the UIL part inside) :

```
public class AdapterDirectories extends BaseAdapter {
    /**
     * PRIVATE ATTRIBUTES
     */
    // LOG
    private static final String     TAG             = AdapterDirectories.class.getSimpleName();
    // IHM
    private static LayoutInflater   _inflater       = null;
    private Activity                _activity;
    // DATA
    private DataManager             _dataManager;
    private ImageLoader             _imageLoader;
    private DisplayImageOptions     _options;
    private int                     _section;
    private float                   _latitude;
    private float                   _longitude;
    private List<Contact>           _listContacts   = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    private List<Favoris>           _listFavoris    = new ArrayList<Favoris>();

    public AdapterDirectories(Activity activity, boolean favoris, float latitude, float longitude, int section) {

        this._activity = activity;
        this._latitude = latitude;
        this._longitude = longitude;
        this._section = section;
        //
        ContactRepository contactRep = null;
        //
        if (favoris == false) {
            _listContacts = EtablissementApplication._dataManager.get_listOfContacts(_section, _activity);
        }
        else {
            // FAVORITE
            this._listFavoris = EtablissementApplication._dataManager.get_listOfFavoris();
            // DATA
            contactRep = new ContactRepository(_activity);
            contactRep.Open();
            for (Favoris unFavoris : _listFavoris) {
                _listContacts.add(contactRep.GetById(unFavoris.getIdentifiantContact()));
            }
            contactRep.Close();
        }
        _inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this._imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        this._options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.error).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error).cacheInMemory().cacheOnDisc()
                .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(Utils.IMAGE_BORDER_RADIUS)).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();
        Utils utils = new Utils();
        utils.setImageLoader(_imageLoader, _activity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return _listContacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        CellHolder cellHolder = null;
        Contact _contact = _listContacts.get(position);
        Etablissement etablissement = new Etablissement();
        //
        // GET
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.directory_list_item, null);
            cellHolder = new CellHolder();
            cellHolder.textTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.annuaire_titre_etablissement);
            cellHolder.textCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.annuaire_categorie_etablissement);
            cellHolder.textDistance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.annuaire_distance_etablissement);
            cellHolder.imageIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img_icon);
            cellHolder.textPromo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.promo);
            cellHolder.textTarif = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.annuaire_tarif_etablissement);
            view.setTag(cellHolder);
        }
        else {
            cellHolder = (CellHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        //
        // SET
        cellHolder.textTitle.setText(_contact.getName().toUpperCase());
        try {
            //
            EtablissementRepository etablissementRep = new EtablissementRepository(_activity);
            etablissementRep.Open();
            int idEta = etablissementRep.GetByIdContact(_contact.getIdentifiant());
            etablissement = etablissementRep.GetById(idEta);
            etablissementRep.Close();
            // CATEGORIES
            if (_section == 0) {
                if (etablissement.getSection() != null && !etablissement.getSection().getLibelle().equals("")) {
                    cellHolder.textCategory.setText(etablissement.getSection().getLibelle());
                }
                else {
                    cellHolder.textCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            else {
                String categories = "";
                for (Categorie cat : etablissement.getCategories()) {
                    categories = categories + cat.getLibelle() + "|";
                }
                if (!categories.equals("")) {
                    cellHolder.textCategory.setText(categories);
                }
                else {
                    cellHolder.textCategory.setText(_activity.getString(R.string.txt_no_categories));
                }
            }
            //
            // TARIF
            String trancheTarif = "";
            if (etablissement.getTarif() != null) {
                trancheTarif = etablissement.getTarif().getMinPrice() + "\u20ac à " + etablissement.getTarif().getMaxPrice() + "\u20ac";
            }
            if (!trancheTarif.equals("") && etablissement.getTarif().getMinPrice() > 0 && etablissement.getTarif().getMaxPrice() > 0) {
                cellHolder.textTarif.setText(trancheTarif);
            }
            else {
                cellHolder.textTarif.setText("- \u20ac à - \u20ac");
            }
            // PROMO
            boolean etatPromotion = false;
            for (Promotion promo : etablissement.getPromotions()) {
                if (promo.isPromoOnGoing()) {
                    etatPromotion = true;
                }
            }
            if (!etatPromotion) { // PROMO OFF
                cellHolder.textPromo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else { // PROMO ON
                cellHolder.textPromo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            // LOGO
            final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.loading);
            _imageLoader.displayImage(etablissement.getImgThumb(), cellHolder.imageIcon, _options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                    String message = null;
                    switch (failReason.getType()) {
                        case IO_ERROR:
                            message = "Input/Output error";
                            break;
                        case DECODING_ERROR:
                            message = "Image can't be decoded";
                            break;
                        case NETWORK_DENIED:
                            message = "Downloads are denied";
                            break;
                        case OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                            message = "Out Of Memory error";
                            break;
                        case UNKNOWN:
                            message = "Unknown error";
                            break;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        // DISTANCE
        int distanceFormatee = 0;
        if (_latitude == 0 || _longitude == 0) {
            cellHolder.textDistance.setText("");
        }
        else {
            int distance = (int) distanceBetween(_latitude, _longitude, _contact.getLatitude(), _contact.getLongitude());
            distanceFormatee = distance / 1000;
            if (distance < 1000) {
                cellHolder.textDistance.setText("< 1 km");
            }
            else {
                cellHolder.textDistance.setText(distanceFormatee + " km");
            }
        }
        //
        // SAVE DISTANCE
        EtablissementApplication._dataManager.get_listOfContacts(_section, _activity).get(position).setDistance(distanceFormatee);
        //
        // DATA SAVE
        List<Integer> _mapData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        _mapData.add(_contact.getIdentifiant());
        _mapData.add(etablissement.getIdentifiant());
        DataManager._contactForEtaHashMap.put(_contact.getName(), etablissement);
        DataManager._mapContact.put(position, _mapData);
        return view;
    }

    public class CellHolder {
        public TextView     textTitle;
        public TextView     textAdress;
        public TextView     textCategory;
        public TextView     textTarif;
        public TextView     textPromo;
        public ImageView    imageIcon;
        public TextView     textDistance;
    }

    public void clearData() {

        _listContacts.clear();
        _listFavoris.clear();
    }

    private double distanceBetween(float lat_a, float lng_a, float lat_b, float lng_b) {

        float pk = (float) (180 / 3.14169);
        float a1 = lat_a / pk;
        float a2 = lng_a / pk;
        float b1 = lat_b / pk;
        float b2 = lng_b / pk;
        float t1 = FloatMath.cos(a1) * FloatMath.cos(a2) * FloatMath.cos(b1) * FloatMath.cos(b2);
        float t2 = FloatMath.cos(a1) * FloatMath.sin(a2) * FloatMath.cos(b1) * FloatMath.sin(b2);
        float t3 = FloatMath.sin(a1) * FloatMath.sin(b1);
        double tt = Math.acos(t1 + t2 + t3);
        return 6366000 * tt;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please put any single screen short here. so it will be emboss the idea

Comment: Have you customized your ListView? something like onScrollListener or any thing special?

Comment: Nop i'm using the plain ListView see my edit

Comment: i've three listview in the application only one is refreshing correclty (they are the same) the only diference is two are in the same activity (2fragments in view pager) and the other is in another activity

Comment: Where are you calling `setImageBitmap()` for `imageView` ?

Comment: I am using universal image loader which works perfectly, you give the url the imageview and it does the work. It manage the background threads for you. I ll try to move around the UIL code..

Comment: @Yume117 progress bar is always visible or after few second it becomes invisible.

Comment: Nop the progress is always visible until you slide (until the views are recycled)

Comment: I usually use my own ImageLoadingView component that always acts normally. https://github.com/sherifelkhatib/Android-Universal-Image-Loader-Wrapper

Comment: Let me get it right, when you scroll down your list you get images, but when you scroll up you don't want to show the progress bar, and directly want to show the image already downloaded, is this the case???

Comment: Not really,  as i said using UIL you can show an image when the download failed, and a progress while it is still downloading. What i want is to display the image as soon as it is downloaded without having to scroll to recycle the cells

Comment: where is the weak hash map object pls post your code here

Comment: there is no weak hash map. UIL manage the cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve expected behaviour by this:

Your list item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAlbum"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout
```

If you have `ProgressBar` and `ImageView` in this order, then ImageView will overlay the ProgressBar, when Image Loader set image into it so `ProgressBar` will not be visible anymore.

Then in your `getView()` method just simply load image with standard way. You dont have to bother with hiding/showing `ProgressBar`

Comment: Still the same behavior, the spinner stay, the imageview doen't show =(

Comment: How do you load that image?

Comment: Yes I know that you use that, I did read your question. I mean send the line of code with displayImage() method after you modified your list item layout by my suggestion.

Comment: ok ;) the method is the same without the setVisibility and invalidate

Comment: And also can you update your question with your full getView() method please? Maybe there is an issue.

Comment: Are you sure that image urls are valid? Try to make LogCat return value of etablissement.getImgThumb() and also make LogCat of onLoadingStarted(), onLoadingFailed() and onLoadingComplete() and send it here.

Comment: The urls are valid since the image are displaying when the cells are recycled. And inside two other listViews in the application there isn't this bug.

Comment: ok i tried something since your last comment. onLoadingComplete is only called when i scroll(and i checked there are no error, no exceptions)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37343/discussion-between-traninho-and-yume117)

Comment: The issu was from the use of the variable "view" which i deleted to only use convertview. So only one setTag() was left just before "return" now it's working fine and fast thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to put a function to **refresh the 'source' that is providing the image resource to the spinner manually once the download is complete** i.e i suppose when an **onPost** is complete in your async task if at all u are using one. This way the **source** providing the resource to the spinner will be updated all the time.

Comment: There are no asynctask in my code. And what do you mean by source ?

Comment: What i meant by source is, the container from which the image is supplied to the spinner. For e.g. the source for a listView would be an arrayadapter that way..

Answer (score 0):

try this code and use Asynk task will help u:

http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2012/06/13/lazy-loading-images-from-urls-to-listviews/

Comment: Don't need lazy loading, i'm already using UIL which is more complete